# React native Expo - How I can change permission default message in Android

Tags: android, react-native, expo

How I can change the message in the Dialog that request permissions in Android? I found a solution for IOs but not work for Android development.

Comment: You might consider editing your question and posting a screenshot of the dialog that you are referring to. If it is the system-supplied dialog for permissions, you cannot change the message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it in Android. From their official documentation

> Note: When your app calls requestPermissions(), the system shows a
>   standard dialog box to the user. Your app cannot configure or alter
>   that dialog box. If you need to provide any information or explanation
>   to the user, you should do that before you call requestPermissions(),
>   as described in Explain why the app needs permissions.

For details, you can read here

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html